# React list public files

Tags: reactjs, file

I want to list all the file in the PUBLIC directory with React, do you have any idea how i can do that ?

(And please, don't tell me to use fs, i need it for react, not with Node.js)

Answer (score -2):

I think you can do this using `list-react-files`

list-react-files
https://www.npmjs.com/package/list-react-files

Install

```
$ npm install --save list-react-files
```

Usage

```
import listReactFiles from 'list-react-files'

listReactFiles(__dirname).then(files => console.log(files))
```

Comment: Already did, he use fs, i have this error :

Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): fs.readdir is not a function
▶ 7 stack frames were collapsed.
DashBoard.ListCategory
Category.js:148
  145 | //List de toute les images trouvé
  146 | var dataCategory = []
  147 | //Lecture des fichiers du domaine
> 148 | listReactFiles("/image/domaine/" + GetDomain() + "/categorie/", (err, files) => {
      | ^  149 |     files.forEach(file => {
  150 |         dataCategory.push(file)
  151 |     })